# Java | Return List<Model> on Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle

I've been reading [these Oracle Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm#CACFGDCI) but I couldn't find any example of returning a List (as rows) in the Oracle DB.

I've developed a Java function which returns a `List<JsonPair>`, this is my class

```
public class JsonPair{
  public String path;
  public String value;
}
```

The ideia is to obtain something like this(**see below**) after include my Java function into the Oracle DB

```
|       Path        |   Values  |
|:------------------|----------:|
| root.obj1.attr1   |    Val1   |
| root.obj1.attr2   |    Val2   |
| root.obj2.attr1   |    Val3   |
| root.obj1.arr1[0] |    Val4   |
```

My function receives a JSON `String` and return `List` like mentioned above. The idea is to have something like

```
SELECT 
  Path,
  Value 
FROM 
  MyPLSQLFunction_ThatCallsMyJaveFunction (JsonString)
```

Comment: Are you using any ORM tool, if yes, you can write a constructor and prepare an object as your need. Another alternate is a map where you can store the object. using google's Gson class convert it to a Json object

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I'll edit my question to add more details, but the idea is to do something like **select * from MyPLSQLfunctionThatHasMyJava(json varchar)**